# A task using JavaScript (node.js)

Tags: javascript

I have the following task: check that A do not divide A and B do not divide A
The function must return true / false. In input put 2 integer positive numbers A and B. 1 <= A, B <= 10000

The sample:

> node task.js 5 3
>
> true

The first argument puts in process.argv [1]

My code:

```
function not_divide(a, b) {
    if ((a % b > 0) && (b % a > 0)){
        return console.log(true);
    }
    else{
        return console.log(false);
    }
}

not_divide(process.argv[1], process.argv[2]);
```

The task is very easy, but checker don't want to accept it. Help me, please

Comment: i have done all changes, but problem still exists... I think the problem is not in the code

Comment: The problem was in method of the outputing.
I was need to output with process.stdout.write(), not with console.log, but it wasn't wrote in the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log()` returns undefined...not the values passed to it.

That means your function always returns `undefined`

change

```
return console.log(true);
```

To

```
console.log(true);
return true;
```

Same for the other return

Answer (score 0):

I think You need `process.argv[2]` and `process.argv[3]` instead of `[1]` and `[2]`;
`process.argv[0]` - path to `node.exe`;
`process.argv[1]` - path to script;
`process.argv[2... etc]` - params;